# GC not detected by motherboard, VGA LED on

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure

I built my new PC yesterday, but I have a problem. To begin, here is his config:

- GPU: EVGA RTX 2070 EX
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700
- MB: MSI B450M Tomahawk
- RAM: 2x8GB Corsair Vengeance DDR4
- Power supply: EVGA 600W
- Hard drive: Seagate Barracuda 1TB
- SSD: Western Digital 240GB
- Case: Aerocool CyberX Advance

My problem is this: I installed everything, mounted carefully, and when I started the PC, the fans and the LED panels of the graphics card and the case went on, but the LED VGA of EZ Debug on the motherboard turned on too, signaling the non-detection of the graphics card or a problem during the initialization of the latter (according to the MSI manual). I do not have any possibility of posting. So, I make a lot of unsuccessful attempts, I install the graphics card on another PCI port, I remove it completely, I use the cords provided with it (which change the types of pins, and so I connect to other noises of the power supply), I unplugged 1 then 2 fans to see if it comes from a concern for power, etc. My screen also does not detect the CG when I connect to it in HDMI. I also reset the CMOS as shown on other forums (without any success, since I have not used the PC yet) without success. Each time, the red LED is lit on the motherboard.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Either the graphics card or motherboard has a fault. I suggest returning them for a refund or replacement.